# $(globalfunction).unbind('window','unload')? how can I do this code?

Tags: javascript, window, unbind

$(globalfunction).unbind('window','unload')? how can I do this code?

I want to unbind window.onunload event from the function which is in common.js

how can I do ?

I cannot refactor this common function but can call

```
<div class="pageNum">
  <a onclick="globalfunction();">ABC</a>
</div>
```

I solve this problem with

```
//YES IT WORK!! BUT I DON'T WANT 'TAG' SELECTOR  BE 'JQUERY OBJECT'
$('div.pageNum a').not('.disabled').click(function(){
        window.onunload=undefined;
    });
```

but I want to let this globalfunction be trigger

```
// !! OF COURSE THE CODE BELOW IS INVALID CODE !! 
$(globalfunction).event('invoke', function(){
        window.onunload=undefined;
});
 //!! OF COURSE THE CODE BELOW IS INVALID CODE !!
```

**I am just looking for any event similar with 'invoke' fired when jQuery Object(function) used..**

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  But it sounds like you want to replace the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the function by doing :

```
window.onunload=null;
```

if this is not what you want then you need to provide more specific details about what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry, that's not what I need. I add more details

Comment: But what does `$(globalfunction).event('invoke'` mean? It's not really valid jQuery. Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Maybe you just want to remove the `onclick` from element? If you remove the attribute the function won't get called. Or as mentioned in comments overwrite `globalfunction=null`

Comment: sorry , My explanation is so poor

Answer (score 0):

You can use preventDefault to prevent the default action(s) associated to that specific event from being completed. Note that while preventDefault is commonly used to prevent submission when clicking on a form submit button, it actually works for any type of event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault